# How can I use CSS selector with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

When a visitor access my website for the first time, the hamburger menu links flashes for few ms.

**Problem references**
Image: https://ibb.co/bMCQ6x

Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y69U2F9NbtdFlpBmH7kHuKkRljb3KM81/view

I am using WordPress, to fix this problem I am thinking to keep hamburger icon hidden for the mob devices. (Initially while page loading)

So, I added this CSS code in the head section.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px){
.genesis-nav-menu.responsive-menu .menu-item, .responsive-menu-icon {
    display: none;
}
}
```

This works.

But, now I wish that when page finish loading, then I want to display hamburger icon.

Why? Assuming, till that moment jquery.js and responsive-menu.js would be already rendered in the browser. Please help. Thanks

Comment: `.genesis-nav-menu.responsive-menu .menu-item, .responsive-menu-icon` this is what you want to `display:block`?????

Comment: Yes. I want to do something with jquery for .genesis-nav-menu.responsive-menu .menu-item, .responsive-menu-icon css. As selector is quite long, I am not able to adjust.

Comment: $('.menu-item').css({'display': 'block !important'});

Comment: Thanks, going to give a try.

Comment: `$(function() { $(".genesis-nav-menu.responsive-menu .menu-item, .responsive-menu-icon").show(); });`  - what else am I missing on this question?

Comment: If you have any more info/requirements, then please update the question.

Comment: I have edited my question, please see again. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select what you want and then add css :

```
  $(".genesis-nav-menu.responsive-menu .menu-item, .responsive-menu-icon").css('display','block!important');
```

If you want to add **multi** css you have do it:

```
.css({'display':'block','color':'red'});
```

Here is explain:https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/ 
**Or** by `addClass`

```
$(".genesis-nav-menu.responsive-menu .menu-item, .responsive-menu-icon").addClass('selector');
```

**In css you have to add**

```
.selector{
   display:block;
}
```

**For your Edit:**

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  var width = $(window).width();
  if (width < 960){
      $(".genesis-nav-menu.responsive-menu .menu-item, .responsive-menu-icon").css('display','block!important');
  };
});
```

Comment: Tell me if that what you want or you need help...

Comment: Not sure why, I am getting an error. https://ibb.co/bMCQ6x

Comment: It says 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token'

Comment: see my edit just add $(" ")

Comment: `<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 960px)').matches) {
  jQuery(.genesis-nav-menu.responsive-menu .menu-item, .responsive-menu-icon).css('display','block!important');
});
</script>`

Comment: my mistake I forgot quotation marks

Comment: what now???is it help???

Comment: Finally, I tried this way. 

`<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 960px)').matches) {
  jQuery(".genesis-nav-menu.responsive-menu .menu-item, .responsive-menu-icon").css('display','block!important');

}
});
</script>`

Comment: Fine if it helps Irealy appricate if you mark as answer (green v)

Comment: In console, there is no error. Perhaps code is running fine. But, I was hoping to turn this CSS of head `@media only screen and (max-width: 960px){
.genesis-nav-menu.responsive-menu .menu-item, .responsive-menu-icon {
    display: none;
}
}` into display: block; to show element when DOM become ready. This is my goal.

Comment: So it works or not??

Comment: @GulshanKumar your comments do not match your question - please update the *question* with an edit to add additional information

Comment: It is **not** working for me as expected. However, I am NOT getting any error regarding jQuery, thanks for your kind help. I wish I could vote, but don't have enough repo. :(

Comment: Do your screen 960px or more??

Comment: by the way you can Mark an answer....

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check again.

Comment: see my edit please

Answer (score 0):

Your code has both JavaScript and Css, you can't do that.

You can add the style to a CSS file like this:

```
.genesis-nav-menu.responsive-menu .menu-item, .responsive-menu-icon {
  display: block !important;
}
```

Or you can change the CSS from the JS/Jquery code like this:

```
$('.genesis-nav-menu.responsive-menu .menu-item, .responsive-menu-icon').css({'display': 'block !important'});
```

Comment: in js not add style like your answer only jquey

Comment: My responsive menu item show up before page load. So I am thinking to hide it intially, but when document become ready, then I want to display it. Ref video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y69U2F9NbtdFlpBmH7kHuKkRljb3KM81/view